# How do you calculate the force a Van de Graaff generator exerts on a grounded sphere?

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

I know that the formula is

$$F = \frac{kQ^2}{r^2} \tag{1},$$

but what exactly is this $r$? is it the distance between the centers of the two spheres or the distance between the surfaces of the spheres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the distance between the centers of the two spheres

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason for this? Because I would think it should be the distance between the surfaces, since it is the surfaces of the spheres that are charged.

Comment: Ya but which on surface will you take? there are infinite points on the sphere? It is also correct. Taking all the interactions between all the points on the surface will also result in the same result. But in short, theses spheres behave as though they are point charges located at their centres

Comment: thank you for your help. Sorry that I did not accept the answer, it is because I am a new user and did not know how.